# paypal recurring NVP

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing, nvp

I am using php code for `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` method with following NVP Request:-

```
VERSION=86
METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
TOKEN=ABCX123V
PROFILESTARTDATE=2014-09-17T04:58:00Z
DESC=Test Payment
BILLINGPERIOD=Week
BILLINGFREQUENCY=6
AMT=1
CURRENCYCODE=USD
IPADDRESS=127.0.0.1
```

My billing period = Week, billing frequency = 6; and profile starts on 17 Sep.,2014; then after 6 week on 29th Oct., 2014 recurring should work. When I check the transaction with `TransactionSearch` method with following NVP Request:-

```
VERSION=86
METHOD=TransactionSearch
STARTDATE=2014-09-01T03:38:48Z
PROFILEID=I-AB2FGH38BDA3
```

NVP Response:-

```
[L_TIMESTAMP0] => 2014-09-17T05:04:55Z
[L_TIMESTAMP1] => 2014-09-18T03:23:50Z
[L_TIMESTAMP2] => 2014-10-30T14:09:36Z
[L_TIMEZONE0] => GMT
[L_TIMEZONE1] => GMT
[L_TIMEZONE2] => GMT
[L_TYPE0] => Recurring Payment
[L_TYPE1] => Recurring Payment
[L_TYPE2] => Recurring Payment
[L_EMAIL1] => test@domain.com
[L_EMAIL2] => test@domain.com
[L_NAME0] => Test Buyer
[L_NAME1] => Test Buyer
[L_NAME2] => Test Buyer
[L_TRANSACTIONID0] => I-NAR3FUC7SAHA
[L_TRANSACTIONID1] => 7AZ3079982647961N
[L_TRANSACTIONID2] => 5MP14432TD321593W
[L_STATUS0] => Created
[L_STATUS1] => Completed
[L_STATUS2] => Completed
[L_AMT1] => 1.00
[L_AMT2] => 1.00
[L_CURRENCYCODE1] => USD
[L_CURRENCYCODE2] => USD
[L_FEEAMT1] => -0.33
[L_FEEAMT2] => -0.33
[L_NETAMT1] => 0.67
[L_NETAMT2] => 0.67
[TIMESTAMP] => 2014-10-31T12:13:44Z
[CORRELATIONID] => b20bec6476812
[ACK] => Success
[VERSION] => 86
[BUILD] => 13443904
```

Transaction starts on 17 Sept, 2014 and then why paypal do transaction on 18 Sept, 2014 and calculate 6 weeks from 18th Sept, 2014 and so last transaction is on 30 Oct, 2014

And next payment due date is on 10 Dec, 2014

Please guide me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/)

> Note The profile may take up to 24 hours for activation.

If you need a payment right now, what you can do is use `INITAMT` and then set your start date for 6 weeks.

Comment: I also update NVP Request by adding INITAMT; then on my paypal personal account it show inital payment $1 on 17 Sept, 2014 and on 18 Sept, 2014 again $1 sent and calculate 6 weeks from 18 Sept, 2014. I want that payment should not deduct on 18 Sept, 2014 and it should calculate 6 weeks from 17 Sept, 2014